# CSS/HTML - Scroll Header before content

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I try to figure out if it is possible to hide only the upper part of the nav-bar. See Img below (green marked area). This should mimic the navbar behaviour like the whatsapp-app.

I am using **material-ui** for this use-case. With my implementation the app-bar only extends again if the **scroll position is < 48px**. On the .gif-file (see below) it extends on every scroll up event. It also looks like the app-bar scrolls only first until it reaches position fixed. After then the rest of the content begins to scroll.

## Edit

I implemented a proof-of-concept, but it is not quite working as expected: [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-krptpp)

My approach looks as follows:

```
export default function TabBar() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [yOffset, setYOffset] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) {
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  function transitionY() {
    const transitionYthreshold = 48;
    return Math.min(transitionYthreshold, yOffset);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });

  function handleScroll() {
    setYOffset(window.pageYOffset);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar
        position="sticky"
        color="default"
        style={{
          transition: 'all 0.1s',
          transform: `translateY(-${transitionY()}px)`
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar style={{ minHeight: '48px' }}>
          <div style={{ width: '30px', marginRight: '1em' }} />
          <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '20px', verticalAlign: 'super' }}>Help-Educate</span>
        </Toolbar>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="fullWidth"
        >
          <Tab label="Home"  {...a11yProps(0)}/>
          <Tab label="Donations"  {...a11yProps(1)}/>
          <Tab label="About Us"  {...a11yProps(2)}/>
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Container>
          {**SomeSuperLongText**}
        </Container>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
         {**SomeSuperLongText**}
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
         {**SomeSuperLongText**}
      </TabPanel>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I created a gif how the behaviour should look like:
[**dropbox-link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vonsmvn4bs4obi8/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the gif somewhere where it actually is animated?

Comment: it is animated. If you download it.

Comment: I have to log into Dropbox to download it, correct?

Comment: @adam just click on "Direct Download" and it will download without signing in to dropbox

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is not the most elegent solution, but after trying around I came up with the following way:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import useScrollTrigger from "@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

function HideOnScroll(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    threshold: 0
  });

  return (
    <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
      {children}
    </Slide>
  );
}

HideOnScroll.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};

export default function HideAppBar(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to Hide App Bar</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
      <Toolbar />
      <AppBar position="sticky">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">Bar will stay</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Container>
        <Box my={2}>
          {[...new Array(20)]
            .map(
              () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`
            )
            .join("\n")}
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

--> Just put another sticky app bar in your content container and modify the useScrollTrigger with threshold option

See it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-cache-rcxen

Comment: I appriciate the effort.Really. But it feels like this approach is really hacky. What do you think about it?

Comment: Hey. I updated the code base. Actually you do not need to wrap anything in a container and add customzied classes. I think this way it is quite neat.

Comment: still not how I expected to be. Do you accasionally have whatsapp on mobile device? there you can see how I meant i the Appbar to be. Greetings Marco

Comment: Actually, on my mobile device, Whatsapp does not have a appbar that is "partly" disappearing. Do you have an website example?

Comment: I updated my question, with my approach and a gif file how it should look at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-azrqoy

I am making the Container with text scrollable (I have left the scrollbars visible, so you can see better what happens, but you can easily remove them with css)

```
<Container
          style={{
          top:48,
          paddingTop:48,
          bottom: - 48,
          scrollTop: yOffset - transitionY(),
          pointerEvents: transitionY()<48?"none":"auto"
        }} className="cont" onScroll={handleInsideScroll}>
```

The trick is to stop `pointer-events` for the container if you want fingers/scrolling to move the page scroll and enable it back if you want to scroll inside. So this is pretty much CSS solution and I personally prefer these more than pushing values with JS - they are smoother and more optimised.

There are two problems:
- when the pointer-events switch happens, you have to move your mouse (1px) to have the scroll work again (This can probably be fixed if you `ref` and manually change `containerRef.style.pointerEvents` instead of setting states and rerendering components.
- the logic of this script doesn't handle scrolling up exactly like your gif animation, you will probably have to detect scrolling up and stop the pointer-events until the bar shows

I have never written a line in TypeScript, so I couldn't really try everything I wanted.

Comment: This solution-approach in general is the closest, but the navbar-logo should appear/disappear on every scroll up/scroll down event. In this case the logo appears only if you scroll to the very top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the whatsapp navbar and I understood what you wanted.

You can actually use the `window.pageYOffset` and set the `style.top` of the `navbar` in the `window.onscroll` function.

A sample is shown in the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll) website which is working as the way you mentioned.